# Copy formulas from one column to variable number of columns

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a Macro which inserts a variable number of columns to the left of column F, based on an inputted number into a userform, less 3.  i.e. if user punches in 6, the macro will add 3 columns to the left of column F (the original columns F, G, and H contain other data).

```
'Code for "done" button in months prompt
Public Sub Done_Button_Click()

Dim ColumnNum%
Dim xNo As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Worksheet In Worksheets
    Worksheet.Unprotect
Next Worksheet


'refernces column "F"
xNo = 6
'References user input from text box (number of months)
y = Add_Columns.Months_Input.Value

For i = 1 To y - 3

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Columns(xNo).Insert Shift:=xlRight

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  - 3

'Move to next column
    xNo = xNo + 1
Next i

'Hide prompt
Unload Me

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Protect All Sheets

On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("DATA").Protect
Worksheets("Input").Protect
Worksheets("Output").Protect
Worksheets("Chart").Protect

'Jump Back to Input Sheet
Sheets("Input").Select
Range("A1").Select

'Save Workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
'User input for number of months
Public Sub Months_Input_Change()
Dim y As String
y = Add_Columns.Months_Input.Value
End Sub

'Tells prompt to reference cell B5 for number of months
Private Sub Userform_Activate()
CMiC_Months.Value = Format(ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value, "0.0")
With Add_Columns
    .Top = Application.Top + 350
    .Left = Application.Left + 350
End With
End Sub
```

I then want to copy the forumlas from column E to the newly inserted columns.  However, no matter how I try to program the copy+paste function, it seems to either copy forumlas from column A and B, or copy over forumlas to the right of the newly inserted range.

What is the best way to copy the values from column E to the newly created columns?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. It's a very powerful way of sweeping all the errors under the carpet and hiding things from you. There are _very_ few cases where it's appropriate to wrap 1 or 2 lines of code with it, and this ain't one of 'em. Comment out `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` until you've got your code working exactly as you want it. That's also hiding things from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking to do, are you trying to copy the formulas or the values? i.e. do you want to preserve the formulas/formatting, or do you only want to keep the actual values that had been calculated in Column E - I think you want the formulas. But here's both solutions:

> I then want to copy the forumlas from column E to the newly inserted columns.

```
For i = 1 To y - 3

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E:E").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Columns(xNo).Insert Shift:=xlRight

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3

    'Move to next column
    xNo = xNo + 1
Next i
```

> What is the best way to copy the values from column E to the newly created columns?

```
For i = 1 To y - 3

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Columns(xNo).Insert Shift:=xlRight

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Range("E:E").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Columns(xNo).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(10, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3

    'Move to next column
    xNo = xNo + 1
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks Valon, the first solution is the one I was looking for!